# Send message to set of users within a group with SignalR

Tags: signalr

Is it possible to send a message to a selection of clients within a Group in SignalR?

...without having to maintain your own lists of subscribers and using `context.Clients.Clients(includeConnectionIds[])`

Answer (score 1):

SignalR does not have state by default, or they actually do with groups... But it is not very dynamic. I had the same issue as you are having. I needed to send a message to a subset of a group.. Or actually I needed to send to clients where age was between x and y...

This is impossible with groups so you have to implement the functionality your self.
Bloated and ugly...

I actually ended up using Xsocket.net instead where I can target client with lambda expressions without messing around with custom static lists/groups etc.

Do not know your requirements but sending to any subset if clients is done by:

```
this.SendTo(p => p.Age > x && p.Age < y, new {Message="hello world"},"message");

//Signature of the extension method is...
//SendTo<T>(this IXSocketController socket, Func<T, bool> expression, object obj, string eventname)
//So you can actually send to clients on any controller is specifying T
```

Best of luck with whatever you choose.

Answer (score 0):

In SignalR 2.0 you can send to a many groups or many connections in a single call via Clients.Groups or Clients.Clients.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to send to a subset of a group? Eg:
 context.Clients.Group(groupName, onlySendToTheseClients).broadcastMessage(...);

Comment: You can send to everyone in the group and exclude certain connections or you can send to individual connections or a group of connections.

Comment: @davidfowl: How do you send it to a particular user in a group? like; _signalrContext.Clients.Group("groupName").User("userid").sendMessage?

Comment: There's no way to do that. You can send to the user and pass the group name as an argument so you know the context.